# Given any $k\in\Bbb{N}$ there exists $k$ consecutive composite integers such that reciprocal of each composite integer is a Cantor point then $k=1$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, soft-question, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set

**Conjecture**: Given any $k\in\Bbb{N}$ there exists $k$ consecutive composite integers with the property that reciprocal of each composite integer is Cantor points then $k=1$.

---

$x$ is a Cantor  point iff $x\in\mathcal{C}$$($Cantor's middle-third set$)$ i.e $x=\sum_{n\in\Bbb{N}} \frac{a_n}{3^n}$ where $a_n\in\{0, 2\}$.In other words base-$3$ expansion or ternary expansion of $x$ contains only $0$ and $2$ and if contain $1$ then it can be replaced by a strings of $2$'s.

---

Attempt:

For $k\ge 1$ , the set $S_k=\{(k+1)!+j:2\le j\le k+1\}$ is a set of $k$ consecutive composite integers.

For $k=1$ , $(1+1)! +2=4$ and $\frac{1}{4}=(0.\overline{02})_3$

For $k= 2$ ,  $S_2=\{8,9\}$

But $\frac{1}{8}=(0.\overline{01})_3\notin\mathcal{C}$ and $\frac{1}{9}=(0.{01})_3\in\mathcal{C}$

---

$1)$Can we construct a different set $S_k$ which satisfy all requirements?
Or
$2)$ there is no  $m, n\in\Bbb{N}$ consecutive composite number such that both $\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{n}\in\mathcal{C}$ ?

Answer to the second question is negative$[(m, n)=(9, 10) ]$

Comment: I don't understand the attempt...it looks like you just guessed a particular set which doesn't work. Have you tried to enumerate those $n\in \mathbb N$ for which $\frac 1n$ is in the Cantor set?  I'd list the first dozen or so and try to detect patterns.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it, my guess is that it is hard.  [A054591](https://oeis.org/A054591) is the sequence of natural numbers $n$ such that $n$ is the denominator for *some* rational number in the Cantor set ($146$ is in the sequence because $\frac 5{146}$ is in the Cantor set, for instance).  You'll see plenty of consecutive pairs but no triples, though the list is short.   I note that for most of these numbers, $\frac 1n$ is actually in the sequence but I'd generate that sequence separately.

Comment: Oh, [A121153](https://oeis.org/A121153) is the exact list you are looking for, though this one is even shorter than the other.  I note that it is (to me) surprisingly similar to [A005836](https://oeis.org/A005836)  which is just the list of natural numbers such that $1$ doesn't appear in their base three representation.  Not immediately sure why those lists ought to be similar...  The first element of the former that does not appear in the latter is $949$.

Comment: Interesting.....

Comment: As I said, I don't know how to solve it.  I gave you my thoughts on how to start.  I note that the sequence A005836 obviously can't contain three consecutive integers so, had it been true that your sequence was a subsequence, that would be enough.  As I said, that isn't exactly true but it seems very close.  Maybe there's something along those lines.  Maybe not.

Comment: @lulu Both A054591 and A121153 have longer lists under the "Links" section.

Answer (score 2):

No three consecutive integers have their reciprocals in the Cantor set.

Proof:
Suppose $n \equiv 2 \pmod {3}$. Then $\frac{1}{n}$ has a purely periodic base-$3$ expansion:
$$\frac{1}{n} = \frac{P}{3^r} + \frac{P}{3^{2r}} + \frac{P}{3^{3r}}+ \ldots = \frac{P}{3^r-1}$$
for some positive integers $r$ and $P < 3^r$. But then
$$P = \frac{3^r-1}{n} \equiv 1 \pmod{3},$$
so the base $3$ expansion of $\frac{1}{n}$ has a $1$ in it. So for $n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, $\frac{1}{n}$ is not in the Cantor set.

Comment: Thanks!  (+1) I was definitely over thinking this.